# Taylor Series on two variables simultaneously

Tags: discrete-mathematics, taylor-expansion

I need to find Taylor series of u($x_i+h,t_n+k)$ where taylor series of $u(x_i,t_n+k)$ and $u(x_i+h,t_n)$ are given as such.

[image]

[image]

Is it basically the summation of both the terms except $u(x_i,t_n)$? Am i right?

Comment: There are "cross terms" (coming from mixed partials) as well. You might expand _each term_ in your first series as a series in powers of $h$ using the second series, and use equality of mixed partials as needed to combine terms.

Comment: can show how it done?